# Хэш-функция, для чего она нужна

Tags: хеширование

Для чего вообще нужна хэш-функция, что означают цифры, которые она возвращает, и как и какие можно решать задачи с помощью нее?

Comment: как правило для шифрования данных

Comment: @johniek_comp, надеюсь, что вы шутите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вам [такой](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хеширование#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.85.D0.B5.D1.88-.D1.84.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B9) ответ?

**Польза** с хэширования в том, что обратное преобразование *почти* невозможно. Почти, потому что мощности растут и при большом желании и некотором вложении можно даже перебором определить, что там захэшировано.

Примеры на PHP, но, думаю, разберетесь.

**Простейший пример** с использованием `md5()`, которую уже не рекомендуют и без солей.
При регистрации:

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];  // получаем имя (!)
$password  = $_POST['password'];   // получаем пароль (!)
$password  = md5($password);       // хэшируем

save_to_db($user_name, $password); // сохраняем их в БД
```

При авторизации:

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name']; // получаем имя
$password  = $_POST['password'];  // получаем пароль
$correct_pass_hash = load_user_passhash($user_name); // загружаем пароль из БД

if ($correct_pass_hash == md5($password)) // проверяем совпадают ли хэши
    $logged = TRUE;
```

Идея в том, что хэш *теоретически* должен быть уникальным для уникального набора данных, поэтому не надо хранить пароль в чистом виде - достаточно хэша.

Восклицательные знаки в комментариях из-за того, что нельзя брать данные прямо от пользователя. Должна быть валидация какая-то.

**Второй пример** с активацией почты.
При отправке активационного письма:

```
$hash_link = md5($user_email.$user_id.$current_time); // создали уникальную ссылку
$body = "Перейдите сюда, чтобы активировать почту http://example.com/act/$hash_link";
send_mail($user_email, $body); // отправили почту
```

При переходе пользователя:

```
$user = get_user_by_hashlink($hash_link);
activate_user($user);
```

**Что почитать**

- [Радужная таблица](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Радужная_таблица)
- [Соль](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Соль_(криптография))
- [Коллизия хеш-функции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коллизия_хеш-функции)

Comment: А можете показать пример какой-нибудь несложной программы с использованием хэш-функции?

Comment: @klast Хэшируем большой файл, передаем через ненадежную среду, хешируем на стороне получателя. Если хэши совпали - файл передан полностью, без повреждений

Comment: @neoascetic, можно говорить, о том, что файл передан без повреждений, но не на 100% это утверждать.

Comment: хэшируем пароли зарегистрированных пользователей перед занисеснием в базу, во-первых у всех паролей фиксированная длина, во вторых, даже если злоумышленники получат базу, получить сами пароли будет сложнее

Comment: @klast, обновил вопрос - добавил пример.

Comment: @neoascetic при передаче лучше, конечно использовать контрольную сумму, т.к. она быстрее

Comment: лолшто? а разве контрольная сумма не является результатом хэш-функций?

Comment: @Spectre вообще разница колоссальна: хэш-функции -- это все-таки функции, которые тяжело обратить, а CRC - это просто результат деления файла на полином, и, как результат, CRC быстрее в разы

Comment: тогда правильнее говорить, что контрольная сумма с использованием CRC быдет получена за меньшее время, чем контрольная сумма с использованием хэш-функция

Comment: CRC по своему определению - это, разумеется, тоже хэш-функция. То есть, скажем так, не любая хэш-функция является чексуммой, но любая чексумма является хэш-функцией.

Comment: Хэш теоретически и практически не может быть уникальным для каждого набора данных по той простой причине что он короче. В криптографии хэш по этой причине называют также дайджестом

Answer (score 4):

У хэш-кодов очень широкое применение. Примеры:

1. Проверка целостности файлов. Считаем некую ф-цию от входного набора данных и сохраняем ее значение. Если при следующем пересчете значение изменилось - файл изменился. Это может указывать на то, что произошел сбой в процессе его передачи или во время хранения. Ну, или кто-то его изменил.
2. Хранение паролей в БД. Как известно, в базе данных пароли хранить в отркрытом виде - очень плохая идея. Дело в том, что БД могут поломать и тогда взломщик сможет узнать все пароли. Чтоб этого не произошло в базах данных хранят хэши паролей. И уже сравниваются хэши. Хэши одинаковы - значит, пользователь ввел пароль верно. В данном случае, на хэш-коллизии обычно не обращают внимания.
3. Хэши еще очень удобно использовать в качестве индекса для поиска каких-нибудь нетривиальных данных. Но это перекликается с п.1. Например, есть сотни тысяч строчек и среди них есть одинаковые. Вместо того, чтобы сравнивать каждую с каждой, проще посчитать хэши и разбить их на группи с одинаковым хэшем. Понятно, что строчки с разным хэшем будут априори разные, а вот внутри группы уже придется проводить посимвольное сравнение.

Примеров можно привести еще много....

Answer (score 0):

Еще Хэш применяется в мемкэшэ, запрос хэшируется, данные кэшируются. Позже по этому хэшу данные извлекаются из кэша.